# How do I toggle a hidden overlay with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a [page](http://rouviere.com/new/websites) that will have multiple work samples and want to be able to display a hidden overlay on each element when you mouse over the image. I have two samples in place. The initial hover to display the hidden overlay currently displays the overlay on both. I want to limit the display to the individual elements and then be able to hide the overlay when you mouse out or click on the overlay.

Here is the HTML:

```
          <div class="project col-sm-6">
           <a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/{url_title}">
              <img src="/images/tmp-website-1.jpg" alt="replace" class="img-fluid" />
            </a>
            <div class="overlay" style="display: none;">
                <div class="text">
                <h3>Project Title</h3>
                <p>Project Summary</p>
                <p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/">VIEW</a></p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- overlay -->
        </div><!-- project -->
```

The CSS:

```
.project { 
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.overlay { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .9;
 }

.text { width: 75%; height: 30%; margin: 50px auto; text-align: center; }
```

The jQuery:

```
$( '.project_link' ).hover(function() {
  $( '.overlay' ).show( );
});
$('.overlay').click(function() {
  $( '.overlay' ).hide( );
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No much point in using jquery for this. Just use pure css.

```
.project:hover .overlay{
  display:block;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
  display:none;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.project {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project:hover .overlay{
  display:block;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
  display:none;
}

.text {
  width: 75%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project col-sm-6">
  <a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/{url_title}">
    <img src="/images/tmp-website-1.jpg" alt="replace" class="img-fluid" />
  </a>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Project Title</h3>
      <p>Project Summary</p>
      <p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/">VIEW</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- overlay -->
</div>
<!-- project -->
```

Comment: @fmz No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Why not take away the JavaScript and set this using `opacity`. All I would do is set `.overlay` to `opacity:0;` and set a transition so that the overlay comes in nicely and add when `.project` is hovered over, the `overlay` is given `opacity:1;`

```css
.project { 
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    }

.overlay { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
 }

.project:hover .overlay { 
  opacity:0.9;
}

.text { width: 75%; height: 30%; margin: 50px auto; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project col-sm-6">
           <a class="project_link" href="/our-work/project/{url_title}">
              <img src="http://rouviere.com/images/tmp-website-1.jpg" alt="replace" class="img-fluid" />
            </a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="text">
                <h3>Project Title</h3>
                <p>Project Summary</p>
                <p class="view"><a href="/our-work/project/">VIEW</a></p>
                </div>
            </div><!-- overlay -->
        </div><!-- project -->
```

Hope this helps.